# javascript for array comparison statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to compare array1 to array2 items. 
If array(position 1) > array(position1) return as A (+1)
If array(position 1) < array(position1) return as B (+1)
This will keep looping until it finishes and returns 
console.log (A + B). i am new to javascript please help

```
const X= [5,8,7,8];
const Y= [3,6,10,10];
for (var i=0; i < X.length;i++){
   if(x[i] > y[i]) {
      return A++;
   }
   else if (x[i] < y[i]) {
   let B=0
  return B++;
   }
    console.log([A] +[b]);
}
```

Comment: Java? You sure?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an A and B variable and let it have a default value of 0. Don't use `return A++; AND return B++` use `A++; AND B++` and in your `console.log` A and B will do. no `[]` needed like so.

```
<script>
    const X= [5,8,7,8];
    const Y= [3,6,10,10];
    var A = 0;
    var B = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        if(X[i] > Y[i]){
            A++;
        }else if(X[i] < Y[i]){
            B++;
        }
    }

    console.log(A);
    console.log(B);
    console.log(A+B);
</script>
```

Although I still can't comprehend on why did you add up A and B instead of comparing them.

Comment: On your last point: I think they were using a “+” in place of a comma. That also explains their use of the square brackets to actually stop the values being added. To the asker, just use `console.log(a,b);` to output both.

Answer (score 0):

When return is encountered in loop, the control comes out of the loop i.e. the loop breaks.

Also check your variable names. (b -> B, x -> X, y -> Y)

console.log([A] + [B]) has to be outside for loop, if you are looking for final result.

I am not sure, why you are doing "let B=0".

console.log([A] +[B]) gives you 22  (convert numbers to strings and append them) as answer and console.log(A +B) gives you 4 (addition of numbers) as answer. I included both.

Hope this helps.

```
const X= [5,8,7,8];
const Y= [3,6,10,10];
A=0;
B=0;
for (var i=0; i < X.length;i++){
   if(X[i] > Y[i]) {
     A++;
   }
   else if (X[i] < Y[i]) {
     B++;
   }
}
console.log([A] +[B]);
console.log(A + B);
```